# How to remove all static routes from Neutron router using python sdk

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-neutron

Using the python SDK for openstack i am able to add static routes to a neutron router. I can also remove routes, but i cannot remove the last route.

using the `update_router()` function

`update_router(router.id, routes=[])` does not remove the last route
`update_router(router.id, routes=None)` does not remove the last route

its should return the router now has no static route but it doesnt. The last route remains.